# apply function using expand.grid in R

Tags: r, dictionary

I have two vectors `x` and `y`. I create a grid using the following function:

```
v = expand.grid(x, y)
```

I have a function defined as follows

```
N <- function(a, b , dat){
     m = ncol(Filter(function(z) a*max(z)*min(z) < b , dat[1:ncol(dat)]))
     return(m)
}
```

and then I need to maximize `N` over a grid of `x,y`:

```
Maximize <- function(x , y ,dat){
          v = as.matrix(expand.grid(x,y))
          # Here is where I want to map the values of v and get the maximum element and 
          # get the tuple in v that maximized N
          temp1 <- max(apply(v , 1 , N(v[[1]] , v[[2]] , dat)))
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just do `v$x + v$y`? (It may be helpful to think of `v` not as a collection of two-dimensional tuples but as two parallel vectors)

Comment: Hi @DavidRobinson, I plan to use this concept for a more complicated function inside map.

Comment: I am doing some optimization over a grid, so I need to pass a function that takes elements from the cartesian product of the two elements.

Comment: so I want to pass the entire values from the grid to a function, where  function is applied iteratively to each of the elements in the list, which then I can take the minimum of.

Comment: You'll probably want to provide more context in the original question.

Comment: Ok let me see if I can do better.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` both numeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` for this:

```
apply(v, 1, myfunction)
```

Where `myfunction` is your function (you've clarified in the comments that it is more complicated than just addition). `1` means that you want to apply over the rows (`2` would mean to apply to the columns).

If `x` and `y` are both numeric (or both character vectors)*, you certainly want to turn `v` into a matrix first:

```
apply(as.matrix(v), 1, myfunction)
```

This will be more efficient and make the value passed to `myfunction` a vector rather than a one-row data frame.

*However*, if the contents of `myfunction` are some kind of numeric operation, there's a good chance you could vectorize it instead.

---

*If `x` and `y` are both character vectors, don't forget to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your `expand.grid` call.

Comment: Thank you. How can I use the elements of the row as arguments? should do function(x) x[1] + x[2] ?

Comment: A better way to ask I guess is how can I access the element of the rows in the function ?

Comment: @kolonel: Yes, if you followed my advice to use `as.matrix` first. If you applied it directly to the data frame, it would instead be `x[[1]] + x[[2]]`.

Comment: Thank you. It seems  a bit counter-intuitive the way the elements are accessed does it not?

Comment: @kolonel I'm not sure I'd say it's counter intuitive. Again, I'd think a more intuitive (and possibly much more efficient) approach would be to vectorize your operation. If you shared the details of the function I could help.

Comment: @kolonel You're right that I don't see a way to vectorize the operation. Note however that you are using `apply` incorrectly. It would need to be `temp1 <- max(apply(v, 1 , function(r) N(r[1], r[2], dat)))` (or something similar)

Comment: Than you so much. Finally is there a way to get the pair (r[1],r[2]) that gave the maximum value, I dont there is an inverse function here is there?

Comment: @kolonel Just chance `max` to `which.max`, which will give the index of the maximum value. Then you can access the pair with `v[index, ]`

Comment: Excellent thanks, but what if there multiple indices with that property?

Comment: What do you want to happen in that case?

Comment: Hi @DavidRobinson, well the way I have it set up now is first I apply max() to get the maximum of the function and then I redo the calculations using which.max() to get at which values the maximums occured. Ideally, I would like to get the maximum with all the points on the grid that give the maximum. The way I am doing it now is not really good as I have to do the computations twice(first with max() and second with which.max()). I would like to do this using functional programming tools to avoid writing for loops and avoid having functions return multiple values etc...(thanks David again)

Comment: You could create the values first using `vals <- apply(v, 1 , function(r) N(r[1], r[2], dat))`. Then find the indices using which: `indices <- which(vals == max(vals))`

Answer (score 5):

Map will not iterate over rows of your list like that. How about

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 11:13
v <- expand.grid(x, y)
do.call(mapply, c(function(a, b) a+b, unname(v)))
# [1] 12 13 14 13 14 15 14 15 16
```

Here each value is passed as a separate parameter to the function.